# Show that limit of $e^{e^{-xy}}$ as $ x^2+y^2 \to \infty$ does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The problem consists of showing that $\lim\limits_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty}e^{e^{-xy}}$ does not exist. My initial approach was to set $x = t, y = 0$ and show that the function converges to different limits when I let $t \to \infty$ compared to when $t \to -\infty$. From that, I concluded that the function does not have a limit. However, I am not sure whether it is a valid approach to set $y=0$ in this case. Is this the right way to go about it, or should I try some other strategy? I tried using polar coordinates but that does not get me far.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it is the right away. Clearly the product $xy$ may go to either plus or minus infinity and $e^{-xy}$ therefore may go either to 0 or plus infinity. So this limit does not exist.

Comment: If $y=0$, then $$\lim_{x^2+y^2\to\infty}e^{e^{-xy}}=\lim_{x^2\to\infty}e^{1}=e.$$

Comment: *Hint:* Let $y=1$.

Comment: Thanks! What made me unsure about the approach was the fact that when I've used the strategy of setting $y = 0$ previously, I've only examined the limits as $(x,y) \to 0$. I did not know if I could use to to study the limit of when $(x,y) \to \infty$ as well.

Comment: @chrstnsn Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- for $x=y$

$$e^{e^{-xy}}=e^{e^{-x^2}}\to1$$

- for $x=-y$

$$e^{e^{-xy}}=e^{e^{x^2}}\to+\infty$$

thus the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y)=r(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, then

\begin{align}
  \exp e^{-xy} &= \exp e^{-r^2\cos \theta \sin \theta} \\
  &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-nr^2\cos \theta \sin \theta}}{n!}
\end{align}

If $\cos \theta \sin \theta<0$,

$$\lim_{r\to \infty} \exp e^{-xy} = \infty$$

If $\cos \theta \sin \theta=0$,

$$\lim_{r\to \infty} \exp e^{-xy} = e$$

If $\cos \theta \sin \theta>0$,

$$\lim_{r\to \infty} \exp e^{-xy} = 1$$

> The required limit is path dependence and hence limit doesn't exist.